# Pygame not handling keyboard or mouse events properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently reinstalled pygame on my Mac. I installed pygame 1.9.2a0. I have the same version on my windows and the same version before on this very Mac. But I am getting strange results with this new installation. I noticed that all the draw commands work fine, but for some reason clicking on the pygame window does not. The window opens up in the background, it is not normal but it is not a big problem. But then all key presses are redirected to the terminal/IDE (which ever the application was run from). I have attached below a very simple program that I am testing with. The program just looks for the escape key. Note that this works just fine on my windows machine.

TL;DR: Why are keypresses sent to the terminal and not to the pygame window's event loop when the window is selected.

I am baffled by this issue mostly because I have not experienced any issues like this before. I am not really sure how to debug this problem either. If additional information is needed I would be happy to provide them.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 100, 100
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

For the curious:

- MacOSX 10.10.1
- Python 3.4.2 (via pyenv)
- Pygame: 1.9.2a0

**Update:**

I had a theory that there was some sort of issue that appeared in one of the newer commits. So I decided to pull their repository down and revert to previous commits. It seemed rather promising, especially since they had a "big bang" merge of 8 or so pull requests in early January of 2015. So I pulled the repository back to the commit before this massive merging happened and the issue was exactly the same. I decided to do this to a couple of other commits (before and after the merge location) and still no change. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening? *I have not experienced any issues like this*. What's *this*?

Comment: @AJ Pygame should never redirect keypresses to the terminal/IDE when the pygame window is active. Regardless of the code. Pygame somehow redirects those keypresses to the terminal (or IDE). The intention of the test program is when the escape key is pressed the event loop handles the button event and properly exits. This is not done with the current Mac installation, but it does work with the Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a shutdown key without having to use the X in the corner. This is what I did to fix that when I needed to.

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
running = 1

while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():

if event.type == QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    running = 0
elif key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
    pygame.quit()
    running = 0
```

hope this helps.
by the way the escape key doesn't always work so maybe set it to a different key bind.
And for the mouse you need to check the position of the mouse.

```
def run():
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

#check_events
check_events(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to exit the game while pressing the escape key then you should just do the following as your event loop...

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()
```

This will just cover the escape key. You can add the window 'X' button later if you want. There will be some issues between Windows and Apple pygame version.

Hope this helps you with your issue!